# php coding style for global variables/references

Tags: php, coding-style

This is more of a style issue i think but i was wondering how to properly assign a global variable to a function like this:

```
public function getForForm(&$g_aLabels = array(), &$g_aValues = array())
{
   blah that sets the arrays
}
```

when calling this function like `$obj->getForForm($g_aLabels, $g_aValues)` php will start shouting about undefined variables and so on. I want as shortest code possible and wonder if the only way to avoid this is declaring `$g_aLabels` and `$g_aValues` before calling them or if there is some other smart way to do this (and prevent php from displaying these notices)

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested but would:

```
$obj->getForForm($g_aLabels = array(), $g_aValues = array());
```

work fine?

Comment: No. You're passing an expression, not a variable, the result of which is undefined when the function accepts a reference. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php.

Comment: yep that works, but i noticed now that it seems that not declaring them in the function call works in php too, it is just that Zend Studio doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: @tomalak: I read there that when not defining them, they get created, but no notice is made. So then it seems there is something wrong with zend studio.

Comment: Have you tried passing them into the function by reference: `$obj->getForForm(&$a,&$b);`

Comment: @all: we'll just leave it to this. It seems Zend has troubles with it and php doesn't. What i have tested is that calling the function with undeclared variables works fine and is the expected PHP behaviour.

Comment: @half-a-nerd: If you mean that you are using this solution, note my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not clear. Are variables starting "$g_" globals? If so, why are you passing them into a function?

```
$g_aLabels = Array();
$g_aValues = Array();

public function getForForm()
{
   global $g_aLabel, $g_aValues;
   /* you can use these variables now */
}
```

*But*, avoid globals if you can.

Comment: there not globals, he is passing variables by referenced but he does not want to create the variables like your first 2 lines, he wants them streamlined.

Comment: oh well, its just a naming thing. when calling the function you could give them any name like getForForm($output1, $output2) as inside the function $g_aLabel and $g_aValues are references. (it would be better to call them $r_aLabel (to state they are references) 
but like i said, its a naming thing we use.

Comment: @RobertPitt: One should always declare variables before attempting to use them in this manner. "Streamlining" is not an excuse for writing poor or dangerous or incorrect code.

Comment: @half-a-nerd: What does "g_" stand for for you, then? What a horrible naming convention.

Comment: @tomalak: ha ha not so difficult. g_ stands for global and the a stands for array. a global string would then be $g_sVarialbeName (i for int and n for numeric b for boolean). Its just an easy way to find out in what scope a variable is active and what it consists of.

Comment: @half-a-nerd: I asked whether they were globals, and I was told that they are not...